# Video format Files Handling in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, mongodb, jsp

I am storing image and video type data in Mongo Cluster. 
I am able to get the image list from chunk and able to pass the list of images to JSP.
I would like to do same for Videos also like showing the web page with list of videos. How would i do that?

Code for image handling in controller:

```
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(imageForOutput.getInputStream());
    String imageType = StringUtils.substringAfter(imageForOutput.getFilename(),".");
    out = response.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bi, imageType, out);
    out.close();
```

JSP page to Handle the images:

```
<c:forEach items="${images}" var="image"> 
    <img src="getImg/${image[0]}/${image[1]}" width="100" height="100" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: ImageIO is specifically for Images, how can i do for videos. is there any IO for video type?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. 
i did like below, i am placing the code as if some one else face the same issue then they can use it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getVideo/{fileName}/{extension}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getVideo(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName,@PathVariable("extension") String extension,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) 
throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("<<<<i am in video loading method, video name ...."+fileName);
    GridFSDBFile imageForOutput = loginDelegate.getImageBasedOnName(fileName);
    //OutputStream out = null;

    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+imageForOutput.getFilename().replace(" ", "_"));
    InputStream iStream = imageForOutput.getInputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(iStream, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
```